# Cant get rid of red outline that appeared around all paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator

These red line appeared over every path in the design I was working on and I cant seem to get rid of it, it even appears when the image in exported. I know it must have been caused by a button I pressed by accident but cant seem to work out what by googling the problem. Changing the path color just changes the color under the red lines. Would love some help with this!
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried *undo*ing until it reverts?

Comment: I stupidly tried opening and closing the document before trying this so cant anymore

Comment: Can you select everything and include a new screenshot *including* the appearance panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably applied an (outline?) effect to all the shapes, try going to the *Appearance Panel* and deleting any unwanted effects.

**Window → Appearance** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

[image: Appearance Panel]

Select the un-desired effect and *Delete*

Since this is altering everything on one layer, the stroke *may* be applied to the Layer itself.

[image]

Highlight the **layer** in the Layers Panel, then check the **Appearance Panel** for a stroke and remove it.

Comment: I don't think that's it but it does only seem to affect the one layer, so I could just copy and paste it all to a new layer. But I guess that doesn't really help anyone else who might have the issue

Comment: Actually that was totally it! Just had to click through the selection portion of the appearance menu a couple of times. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hope you don't mind @WELZ ... if you do .. shoot me and roll it back `:)`

Comment: @Scott will a watergun work?  (Of course I don't mind, thanks!)

Comment: Depends on what the water gun is filled with... `:)`

Comment: In my case the layer itself had a conture (listed in appearance panel with the layer selected).